# Automate setup of keyboard shortcuts in KDE5

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, automation, shell-script, kde

Can the configuration of keybindings in KDE be scripted? I know the shortcuts are probably stored somewhere in `~./config`, but the files doesn't appear to be in a stable or easily scriptable format. So a script that modifies those files directly would likely break in the next point release of KDE.

The keybindings I'm trying to add are among others `Ctrl+t` to open a new tab in konsole, `Win+d` to focus desktop and `Alt+F5` to maximize window.

I've looked at the commands `qdbus` and `kwriteconfig5` which seems like they could work. But I haven't found the right way to call them to setup keybindings.

Answer (score 2):

The shortcuts for KDE use to be located in `kdeglobals`, but at some point in the past they changed location. I have now found them in

```
          $HOME/.kde/share/config/kglobalshortcutsrc
```

It is a file with many different sections, I will show just one:

```
      [plasma-desktop]
      Next Activity=Meta+Tab,Meta+Tab,Next Activity
      Previous Activity=Meta+Shift+Tab,Meta+Shift+Tab,Previous    Activity
      Show Dashboard=Ctrl+F12,Ctrl+F12,Show Dashboard
      Stop Activity=Meta+S,Meta+S,Stop Current Activity
      SystemTray-Klipper-32=,Ctrl+Alt+V,
      SystemTray-Klipper-6=Ctrl+Alt+V,Ctrl+Alt+V,
      SystemTray-Klipper-80=,Ctrl+Alt+V,
      _k_friendly_name=Plasma Desktop Shell
      manage activities=Meta+Q,Meta+Q,Activities...
```

Comment: I don't have that file, but a similar one in `~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc`. It doesn't look suitable to scripting for me because it contains internationalized strings.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist What are internazionalized strings?